# property id does not exist on antd tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm using umijs and dva. I use id in `Menu.item` in antd. I can run it correctly with dev. But when I build the project and run `serve` on directory dist, `router.push` can not work.

I have used `<Fragment>` or `<div>` set to `<Menu.Item>` like

```
<Fragment id="1"><Menu.Item></Menu.Item></Fragment>
```

and it just not work.
here is my code:

```
<Menu.Item key="9" id="1">door</Menu.Item>
```

It shows Menu.Item does not exist id.But I want to know how to set id to this tag.

And I'm using typescript.